# WinRT XAML How to get current text of a textbox when using Win8nl EventToCommandBehaviour

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have been trying to figure this out for ages and I am stumped.

I have the following XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding MyName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200">
            <WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Win8nl_Behavior:EventToCommandBehavior Event="TextChanged"  
                                                        Command="TextChangedCommand" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=MyTextBox, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </WinRtBehaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>

        </TextBox>
```

And in my View Model:

```
        public ICommand TextChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<string>((p) =>
            {
                var msg = new MessageDialog(string.Format("Hi there {0}", p));
                msg.ShowAsync();
            });
        }
    }
```

But the string value I am hoping to appear in the CommanParameter (p) is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behaviors are not part of the Visual Tree, so they don't have access to the XAML scope and the capability to perform ElementName bindings. This [blog post](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=237) provides more details, and a suitable solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is to pass in the text value as the CommandParameter.